# How to use a class to create the SQLite table and ignore the fact that it is a List<ChildrenObjectModel>?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I'm using a class to generate an SQLite table, but I also want to use it as ItemSource for a two levels ListView (A listview with sub items).

This works for the ListView:

```
public class ParentModel:List<ChildrenModel>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string attributeA { get; set; }

    public ParentModel() {

    }
```

}

But when I do `mySQLiteConnection.CreateTable<ParentModel>();` it throws an Exception because the Object is a List<>.

I can [Ignore] attributes, but is there a way to ignore the fact that the the class is a List<>?

I can also create a List variable inside the model and [Ignore] it, but this wouldn't work for the ListView.

The only solution I can think is creating two classes with the same attributes, one being a List<> and the other one not.

But I really don't like this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to inherit from `List<ChildrenModel>`. You should make the `ChildrenModel` class a class that can create a table, and then that table would have all of the `ChildrenModel` items. Then in `ParentModel` you could have a public property of type `List<ChildrenModel>` which you can load from the ChildrenModel table. You would want to ignore that property as SQLite can not store a `List`. You can then access your populated List through the public property for the `List<ChildrenModel>` in the `ParentModel` class. That's what I would do anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is an option.m that I ended up using. But not what I wanted. I wanted that way so I can use the same model for sqlite and for a two levels list view.